# Permissions when trying to zip through SSH

Tags: bash, shell, heredoc

I don't how to get permissions to run `zip` command on the remote server. When I am on the server running this command: `sudo -u the_user bash` fixes this but when running this through ssh connection generates error: `zip I/O error: Permission denied`

This generates this error:

```
ssh "${SERVER}" \
  "bash -s" <<'ENDSSH'>&1
        zip -r "${DIR_NAME}.zip" $DIR_NAME
ENDSSH
```

If I add `sudo -u the_user bash` like so:

```
ssh "${SERVER}" \
  "bash -s" <<'ENDSSH'>&1
        sudo -u the_user bash
        zip -r "${DIR_NAME}.zip" $DIR_NAME
ENDSSH
```

...I'm getting:
`sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

Comment: You can remove `requiretty` from `/etc/sudoers` or you can try `ssh -tt` to force tty allocation.

Comment: Also your permission denied is on reading "$DIR_NAME" (or writing to the current directory), not on executing `zip` itself.

Comment: so just `ssh $server sudo zip -r $dirname.zip $dirname` ? Why all the `bash -s` and `sudo bash`, - just run zip.

Comment: It is because there is not only one command (zip in that case) but many other command to be run on the server. Sorry for confusion as I haven't put it in the question.

Comment: @jordanm I don't have an access to sudoers file. Why actually I need tty allocation?